# Strange Oracle Timestamp Behaviour

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp, oracle12c, timestamp-with-timezone

I'm stuck.

Oracle shows weird behaviour when handling timestamps, let me explain:

I have a simple table with primary key and an index. `AUDIT_FROM_TS` is a part of a primary key. It's partitioned using `AUDIT_FROM_TS` on a monthly interval.

Relevant DDL

```
CREATE TABLE "SDR"."TRADE_DEAL_F"(
...
"AUDIT_FROM_TS" TIMESTAMP (9) DEFAULT SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(SYSTIMESTAMP) NOT NULL ENABLE,
...
CONSTRAINT "PK_TRADE_DEAL" PRIMARY KEY ("TRADE_DEAL_ID", "VALID_FROM_DT", "AUDIT_FROM_TS")
...
PARTITION BY RANGE ("AUDIT_FROM_TS") INTERVAL (NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1,'MONTH')) 
...
```

When running this query:

```
select count(*) from trade_deal_f where AUDIT_FROM_TS < timestamp '9999-12-31 00:00:00';
```

I get

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>       01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
>       *Cause:    Illegal year entered
>       *Action:   Input year in the specified range

But this one works just fine:

```
select count(*) from trade_deal_f where AUDIT_FROM_TS < timestamp '9999-12-15 00:00:00';
```

I've done a little debugging and if increment the date to the 16th of December 9999, same error is thrown.

Now more debugging...

```
SELECT DBTIMEZONE from dual;
```

returns `+00:00`

```
SELECT SESSIONTIMEZONE FROM dual;
```

returns `Europe/London`

Can anyone help with this  please ? I am not 100% sure it's the timezone issue, as it would be offsetting the date by 2 weeks...

```
select count(*) from trade_deal_f where AUDIT_FROM_TS = timestamp '9999-12-31 00:00:00 Europe/London';
select count(*) from trade_deal_f where AUDIT_FROM_TS = timestamp '9999-12-31 00:00:00 GMT';
select count(*) from trade_deal_f where AUDIT_FROM_TS = timestamp '9999-12-31 00:00:00 UTC';
select count(*) from trade_deal_f where AUDIT_FROM_TS = timestamp '9999-12-31 00:00:00 +00:00';
```

all these seem to be valid...

Comment: Can you try to add UTC timezone to the timestamp literal: `timestamp '9999-12-31 00:00:00 00:00`'

Comment: Hello dnoeth, thanks for contribution... I added the queries, which work (including the timezone).  Unfortunately this does not fix my issue, I have plenty of tables defined in such way and generic job that writes to them. This is the only table showing this behaviour....

Comment: What is the datatype of AUDIT_FROM_TS? (You've given the datatype for VALID_FROM_DT, but that's not what you appear to be using in the query). Could you update your create table statement to include this column as well please?

Comment: my bad, sorry copied wrong column... updated now, other column has same issues

Comment: Playing around with this, if the transition date is increased from the first of a month to the second of a month, the ORA-01841 doesn't hit until 9999-12-17. So it seems to be something to do with the partition range, presumably with some internal calculation going past the end of that month.

Comment: You also can't insert a record >= 9999-12-01, because the partition high value would be 10000-01-01 ([which is mentioned in the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE)). So you if you can't have a date in that month anyway, having your filter < 9999-12-15 doesn't make any practical difference, perhaps?

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for answer. I do have tons of records with date of 9999-12-31, as that denotes "forever" for bitemporal transaction timelines.

Comment: You're using that date in a column which is used to partition with monthly intervals? It's fine as a value that isn't used as a partition key.

Comment: It seems that you are correct Alex, I do not store that value in the "partition" column. Also checked, I cannot store that value in that column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems Oracle is using date rounding when looking for the partition your filter date fits in, and a high-value validity check after December 16th is being rounded up past year 10000.

When you change the data type of your filter by adding a time zone component, the query works because you're forcing a conversion on the column values, which prevents the partition ranges being used; specifying GMT changes the plan from:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                              
| Id  | Operation                 | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                              
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |              |     1 |    13 |   120   (2)| 00:00:02 |       |       |                                                                                              
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE           |              |     1 |    13 |            |          |       |       |                                                                                              
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE ITERATOR|              |   112K|  1430K|   120   (2)| 00:00:02 |     1 |     3 |                                                                                              
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL      | TRADE_DEAL_F |   112K|  1430K|   120   (2)| 00:00:02 |     1 |     3 |                                                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                              


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                     

   3 - filter("AUDIT_FROM_TS"<TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-15 00:00:00.000000000')
```

to

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                   
| Id  | Operation            | Name         | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |                                                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                   
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT     |              |     1 |    13 |   124   (5)| 00:00:02 |       |       |                                                                                                   
|   1 |  SORT AGGREGATE      |              |     1 |    13 |            |          |       |       |                                                                                                   
|   2 |   PARTITION RANGE ALL|              |   112K|  1430K|   124   (5)| 00:00:02 |     1 |1048575|                                                                                                   
|*  3 |    TABLE ACCESS FULL | TRADE_DEAL_F |   112K|  1430K|   124   (5)| 00:00:02 |     1 |1048575|                                                                                                   
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------                                                                                                   


PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT                                                                                                                                                                                      
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):                                                                                                                                                     
---------------------------------------------------                                                                                                                                                     

   3 - filter(SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(INTERNAL_FUNCTION("AUDIT_FROM_TS"))<TIMESTAMP' 9999-12-15                                                                                                                 
              00:00:00.000000000')
```

The implicit `SYS_EXTRACT_UTC` causes it to use `PARTITION RANGE ALL`, which doesn't matter if you're *only* using that high filter (though it's a bit redundant anyway); but might have more of an impact if you were search from a low value too.

But if you have interval partitioning with the transition date as the first of a month, which seems to be the case here, you cannot insert any records with an `audit_from_ts` value in December 9999 anyway, because that would require a partition with a high value of 10000-01-01, which is not a legal date. This is mentioned [in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/part_admin001.htm#BAJHFFBE):

> For example, if you create an interval partitioned table with monthly intervals and the transition point is at January 1, 2010, then the lower boundary for the January 2010 interval is January 1, 2010. The lower boundary for the July 2010 interval is July 1, 2010, regardless of whether the June 2010 partition was previously created. Note, however, that using a date where the high or low bound of the partition would be out of the range set for storage causes an error. For example, `TO_DATE('9999-12-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` causes the high bound to be 10000-01-01, which would not be storable if 10000 is out of the legal range.

So if you can't have values in that month, it doesn't really make any logical difference whether you use 9999-12-31, 9999-12-15, or even 9999-12-01 for your filter. (You could make the query work with 9999-12-31 by making the transition date the 18th of the month, but that would be a bit weird, and you still couldn't insert a record after 9999-12-17).

Oracle don't consider this to be a bug. You can read more about it in My Oracle Support document 1507993.1.

Comment: It seems like a bug to meto be honest. Thank you very much for your answer.That helped a lot!